# « T'inquiètes » ou « t'inquiète » ?

Tags: expressions, conjugaison

For the phrase « ne t'inquiète(s) pas », more precisely for the verb « s'inquiéter », do you conjugate the verb as « t'inquiètes » or « t'inquiète » for « tu » ?

The reason I ask this, is because I seem to be finding some inconsistency as to which is used on the web. [**Reverso**](http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=EN&direction=english-french) says for "Don't worry":

[image: Reverso]

Where I'm seeing it conjugated correctly for « vous » but « tu » is looking more like that of « je ».

[**This conjugation site**](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/french/verb/inquieter_negation-pronominal.html) on the other hand is saying « tu ne t'inquiètes pas » which follows more as I would of thought:

[image: Other site]

So my question is, what is the correct way of conjugating « s'inquiéter » for the phrase « ne t'inquiète(s) pas » ?

**EDIT:** I just realised too, how come the accent on the e changes for  everything but « nous » and
« vous » to accent grave instead of accent aigu ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The imperative form is "ne t'inquiète pas", no "s" needed, that would be an error. I think you are confusing the imperative and indicative moods, which in French follow different conjugation rules.

Present imperative - 2nd person singular: no "s" with regular verbs ending with "-er"

> Ne t'inquiète pas

Present indicative - 2nd person singular: "s" with regular verbs ending with "-er"

> Tu ne t'inquiètes pas

Comment: Oh gosh Greg that actually makes a lot of sense! Merci beaucoup pour la reponse rapide !

Comment: Mais est-ce que tu sais pourquoi l'accent sur le 'e' est different ?

Comment: Mmmh... là, c'est plus compliqué... je pense que cela est du au fait que la syllabe suivante a un "e" muet ou pas... Je ne suis pas sûr de la règle qui décrit cela. Comme "native speaker", je fais naturellement la différence parce que cela s'entend oralement. Pour le "s" final à l'impératif, c'est par contre une faute assez courante même dans les écrits de "native speakers".

Comment: J'ai trouvé ceci, cela me semble une explication simple et correcte: https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frmodeleeeer.php

Comment: Ah merci beaucoup !

Comment: If you really want to impress your teacher: in colloquial French, for the imperative "don't worry", you can even use the  form "t'inquiète!" as a quick, shortened form for "ne t"inquiète pas". There is no confusion possible with the positive form, as it would be "inquiète-toi".

Comment: Oui, en fait je le connais ! Comme dans SMS avec "tkt".  One final question, could you use a colloquial version for formality even though it somewhat goes against the entire point of formality, like « vous inquiétez ! » ?

Comment: No, "vous inquiétez" is not used, even as a plural form and even if adressing a group of friends that you would adress individually as "tu".

Comment: Ah yes, forgot the plural. Alrighty. Thankyou very much Greg ! I leave my questions for 24 hours to attract answers but otherwise you've earned my tick. Merci !

Comment: Note that sometimes even if it's "impératif", you'll have to put an "s", for phonetics reasons: « Discutes-en avec Paul ». Yes, French is full of exceptions. See there: https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-40237.php

Comment: To impress the teacher you do need to say, at a minimum: "t'inquiète pas". ***It is the ne that can be dropped. Not both, in speaking***.

Comment: But I did agree with the answer here.

Comment: @Lambie: "t'inquiète" as a shortened form for "ne t'inquiète pas" is very common , esp. among teenagers. The form has been documented on wiktionary: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%E2%80%99inqui%C3%A8te

Comment: Maybe among teenagers, but among the genpop, it continues to be: t'inquiète pas.

Comment: I can also back up the fact that it's said among teenagers, me being one who speaks to them. However as also noted, I haven't seemed to see any adults use "t'inquiète" sans the "pas".

Comment: *T'inquiète* without *pas* is very common among adults too.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers already concerning the mood, which was imperative and not indicative. No need to expand for too long, the S is dropped from the second singular person final for the verbs in -ER in this mood.

---

I’ll concentrate on your question about the accents varying for every person but *nous* and *vous* in the indicative present. It has to do with the pronunciation. When the T-sound is the last one in a conjugation of this verb *(we except the E caduc)*, the É-sound<sup>1</sup> preceeding it turns into an È-sound<sup>2</sup>, and the accent is changed accordingly. French in general doesn’t have very many cases (if any) of words ending with the É-sound + a consonnant<sup>3</sup>.

- **Inquiéter** is pronounced [ɛ̃.kj**e**.te], and the T-sound doesn’t complete the enunciation of the word.
- **Je m’inquiète** is pronounced [ʒə.mɛ̃.kj**ɛ**t] *(also [ʒə.mɛ̃.kj**ɛ**tə] in some areas or circumstances),* and the last sound of the word is a T (or a caduc E).

Though there are variations in the way É and È are pronounced, this verb follows the general trend.

A few of the other verbs behaving the same way, with various consonants following the É: [abréger](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/abr%E9ger.html) (soft G), [céder](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/c%E9der.html), [légiférer](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/l%E9gif%E9rer.html), [léguer](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/l%E9guer.html) (hard G).

---

<sup>1</sup> [[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)] *in the international phonetic alphabet.*

<sup>2</sup> [[ɛ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)] *in the international phonetic alphabet.*

<sup>3</sup> <sub>Possible exceptions:</sub>

- <sub>Words borrowed from English: email [iːmel] *(the neologism* courriel *is however consistently gaining popularity), freight* and *brace* are commonly borrowed as is in Quebec, but I don’t think they are common in France.</sub>
- <sub>Some words pronounced in a very familiar tone in some areas of Quebec, perhaps also elsewhere: *père, mère, frère, bière* can become [peʁ], [meʁ], [fʁeʁ], [bjeʁ] when spoken out loud.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

When you use the expression *(ne) t'inquiète (pas)* (no 's' here), the used mood is called **impératif** in French :

> - inquiète-toi
> - inquiétons-nous
> - inquiétez-vous

In this case, we don't use the mood **indicatif** (as you said):

> - je m'inquiète
> - tu t'inquiètes
> - il s'inquiète
> - nous nous inquiétons
> - vous vous inquiétez
> - ils s'inquiètent

So here we use the negation of *inquiète-toi* which is *ne t'inquiète pas* and became *t'inquiète*.